# ReactJs --- sending props to children causing issue in rendering in children. UI Rendering not happening "NewsLatest.js"

Tags: reactjs

One component Landing.js has following code::

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NewsSearch from '../NewsSearch/NewsSearch';
import NewsLatest from '../NewsLatest/NewsLatest';
import './Landing.css';
import axios from 'axios';


class Landing extends Component {
 state={
  newsList: []
 }
 componentDidMount(){
  axios.get(`https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=7cK9FpOnC3zgoboP2CPGR3FcznEaYCJv`)
  .then(res=> {
   this.setState({newsList: res.data.results});
  });

 }
 render() {
  // console.log(this.state.newsList);
  return (
   <div className="landing text-center text-white">
    <h1>News Portal</h1>

    <div className="news-search">
      <NewsSearch />
    </div>
     <div className="news-latest">
       <NewsLatest newsList={this.state.newsList}/> 
     </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
export default Landing;
```

When sending props to NewsLatest component, 2 values are getting passed: first as undefined and then when value comes then an array with the values.

In the "NewsLatest.js" file code is :::

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class NewsLatest extends Component {
   newsTitle = (
    this.props.newsList.map(item => (<h2>{item.title}</h2>))
  )
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.newsList);
    return (
      <div>
         <h2>News Latest....</h2>
         {this.newsTitle}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default NewsLatest;
```

Nothing is rendering on the UI. I dont know how to handle that. Kindly suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is that you are not rendering anything (per se) cos `newsTitle` does not return anything.
In your code, `newsTitle` is an object but you need to make it a function.

Modifying `NewsLatest` should fix this though

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class NewsLatest extends Component {
   newsTitle = () => (
    this.props.newsList.map(item => (<h2>{item.title}</h2>))
  )
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.newsList);
    return (
      <div>
         <h2>News Latest....</h2>
         {this.newsTitle()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default NewsLatest;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really apppreciate it. Regards.